# Factory contract deploy external contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, optimization, hardhat-deploy

I have a factory contract that has rather a small size, it contains the deploy function, and is pausable.

I want to extend that contract by adding new features but when I add anything it becomes undeployable due to exceeding size.

I am importing the `child` contract directly into the factory and the child contract is already quite huge. (cannot change or be optimized)

How can I deploy my child contract without including it inside the factory? Can the factory be passed the ABI/bytecode of the child contract after its deployed so we keep them separate?

Answer (score 0):

You can "integrate both contracts"

The way to solve this is to deploy them separately (as you seemed to have guesed). Just make sure that Factory contracts has a function named SetChildContractAddress(_address)

```
SetChildContractAddress(_address){
 CHILD =Child(_address);  //Child variable needs to be declared prior
}
```

Once you have deployed both contracts you just call the SetChildContractAddress() and you give it the ChildContract address.

That way the Factory contract will be able to know where the Child is and thus you will be able to call the functions written inside the Child Contract.

[Link for better explanation](https://medium.com/@blockchain101/calling-the-function-of-another-contract-in-solidity-f9edfa921f4c)